# Php calculator with percent calculation

Tags: php, if-statement, calculator

I need some help to make a PHP calculator! It is a calculator for a construction machine rental. So I will calculate how much it will cost to rent an excavator for "x" days. The first day it will cost 300 and + 200 each day after that. But if you rent it for more than 7 days you will get 20% off and if you rent it more than 30 days you will get 50% off! Please help me!

```
<form action="calc.php" method="get">
    <p>
        <label value="days">Antall dager: </label>
        <input class="field" type="number" min="1" max="50" name="days" value="1">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input id="button" type="submit" value="Regn ut!">
    </p>
</form>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['days'])) {

    @$days = ($_GET['days']);

    $total = 300 + $days*200;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Det vil koste ";
    echo "<span style='color:red;'>";
    echo $total, " KR ";
    echo "</span>";
    echo" å leie en byggtørker i ";
    echo $days;
    echo " dager.";
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the specific problem? This is pretty rudimentary procedural programming. The question isn't even clear enough to help you with a concrete implementation (does the discount apply to the whole order or just the time after 7 days etc.?).

Comment: DONT USE @ TO SURPRESS ERRORS! Always make proper errorhandling. ALso, there is nothing that can go wrong with that line. And `@` makes your code a lot slower!

Comment: I have added the code in my question now

Comment: did you get an answer I was writing one but was put on hold before I could post?

Answer (score -1):

Im not going to give you an solution if you cant show any code, but I can give you a push:

First you do all your calculations. After that, you can see if they can get discount:

```
var $total = 300;
$total+= 200* $numDays; // price per day
```

Now you want to know discount, just use an if/else/elseif:

```
if( $days > 30 ){ /* Do something with the price here, the 50% disacount */ ;}
elseif( $days > 20 ){ /* Do something with the price here, for upto 20days */ ;}
elseif( $days > 7 ){ /* Do something with the price here, 20% discounts */ ;}
```

Comment: _"Im not going to give you an answer"_ - then __why__ have you answered?

Comment: Yes, 'answer' needed to be 'solution'. English is not my native language, I ment 'an answer which you only have to copy/paste`, but As it said, 'pressed save to early'.

Comment: Why new downvote? Because of a bad translation that existed 60secs? It says **solution** for a while now...